# System command from Matlab shell (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, matlab, shell, gmt

I need to invoke gmt command form matlab script. In standard Mac OS shell I have all paths configured and gmt works fine. When I start matlab the result is as follows:

```
>> !gmt

/bin/bash: gmt: command not found
```

When I add paths:

```
>> setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ':' '/Applications/GMT-5.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/lib/']);
```

problem changes to:

```
>> !gmt

dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libnetcdf.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/GMT-5.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/bin/gmt
  Reason: Incompatible library version: gmt requires version 10.0.0 or later, but libnetcdf.7.dylib provides version 9.0.0

gmt: Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I have no idea where to go from here.

On Windows this works great, but I prefer working on mac.

Comment: The Windows version of the command works for Ubuntu Matlab too! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved:

```
setenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH', '/usr/local/bin/');
```